# Object moving by adding force to Rigidbody bouncing off where ground objects met

Tags: unity, collision-detection, physics, rigidbody

I have a object that moving by adding force to rigidbody. With just big flat plane, it works fine but with connected small planes, sometimes(actually not sometimes, a lot) the object bouncing off or rotating to another direction where the planes are met. Planes are placed well, there's no gaps between the planes.

Here's the picture for understanding:
[image]

Now next image shows that object was rotated in left direction(I was just keep pressing forward and it just keep push forward).

[image]

I tried with more mass values, like 30000-50000, still happens. I don't know why this is happening, where should I check to solve this problem?

Any advice will very appreciate it.

P.S. I forgot to mention it, object using Box Collider.

Comment: What collider type is the car? If it’s a box then its edges might get stuck between the planes. Try changing the car into a sphere or a convex shape with less sharp edges.

Comment: @schteppe I used Box collider. Using mesh collider(convex) makes object super jitter, and using capsule/sphere collider makes object hard to control, it just keep rotating and slippery, even I locked the rotation.